# Arithmetic and boolean operation to make 0 to 1, and everything else to 0

Tags: binary, binary-operations

I have a 16 bit binary number $x$, and I want to perform on it a series of operations that will result in: if $x = 0000000000000000$ then $f(x) = 1111111111111111$, and if $x \neq 0000000000000000$, then $f(x) = 0000000000000000$.

Here are the operations I have ($y$ is any 16-bit number) :

1. Binary 16-bit addition $(x+y)$, that ignores overflow beyond the 16-bit.
2. Binary 16-bit subtraction
3. Bitwise 16-bit AND $(x\;\&\;y)$: for example $1111111111111111\;\&\; 1111111111111000 = 1111111111111000$
4. Bitwise 16-bit OR
5. Bitwise 16-bit NOT $(!x)$, for example $!(1111111111111000) = 0000000000000111$

These restraints are because those are the operations my ALU supports. Even If you have a function that requires more than the above operations, please share it, and I will figure out how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you also have binary literals?  Like $f(x) = x \& 0000000000000001$ ?

Comment: @JosephWood He already has bitwise negation available to him, doing a bitwise xor with $\bar 1$ is the same thing.

Comment: How many clock cycles are we talking about for your ALU?  If you need it done in 3 to 4 clock cycles or less, then you'll have to define auxiliary functions.  It might be possible to do in $O(n)$ operations taking advantage of the weird behavior of $(x + x) - x$, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: Do you have add / sub with carry?

Comment: @gammatester yes. Except the carry of the Most significant bit (that is beyond the 16th bit) is ignored.

Comment: @DanielV I don't know that binary literals are, I've tried googling and didn't get it. I don't have those. I'm allowd as many clock cycles as needed

Answer (score 3):

As a first step, here is a function `is0(x)` that returns `1000000000000000` if x is zero
and `0` if x is non-zero.

```
y = x - 1                    //is 1??????????????? if x=0 or x > 1000000000000000
z = (!x) & 1000000000000000  //inverts the highest bit of x, remove all other
w = y & z                   
return w
```

This is independent of any carry in the ALU, and already gives
a non-zero result if x=0 and a zero otherwise.

Now the final tricky function `iszero(x)`that uses carry arithmetic

```
y = is0(x)
add y,y ->(z, carry)   //z is always zero, carry set if x is 0
sbc z,z -> w           //1111111111111111 if x is zero, 0 otherwise
return w
```

The function was implemented and fully tested on a x86 system, here the
code with Intel syntax

```
mov ax,[x]
mov bx,ax
not bx
sub ax,1
and ax,bx
mov bx,0x8000
and ax,bx
add ax,ax
sbb ax,ax
mov [w],ax
```

Comment: This is great, my only problem is that I don't have a carry flag (necessary for the sbb operation). I've been trying to find some way to replace it, and didn't find any. Maybe if I'll give you more context it'll help - I have two numbers stored in cell0 and cell1, and I want cell2 to have -1 if cell0=cell1, and 0 if cell0 != cell1. The only operations I have are the ones I've listed, but I have unlimited clock cycles and storage space. I'm building a VM translator, based on the the ALU I have.

Comment: I now understand what you've asked me if I have add/sub with carry. My addition has carry for all the other bits except the MSB, so 100 + 100 = 000, and the carry gets lost.

Comment: I'm sorry for spamming, but I've looked through the class notes and it might not be possible. Thanks for your help regardless